# My items listview doesn't show the last item

Tags: android, xml, listview

My items `ListView` doesn't show the last item
here is my xml code
when I scroll down my list the last item doesn't show in the items. Need help for this problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/sky_blue"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="8dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Student Projects : "
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvProjects"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="395dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line

```
 android:layout_height="395dp"
```

to

```
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your Viewpager

android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize" because the size you don't have at the bottom is exactly the size taken by your Toolbar

Example with RecyclerView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_trips"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

Example with Viewpager

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager_trip_history"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```